# ¿Porque puede desaparecer una tabla temporal sin cerrar sesion en oracle?

Tags: php, oracle

Cordial saludo

Mi duda es porque se puede desaparecer una tabla temporal privada sin que yo la borre o cierre sesión.
Lo que hice fue crear una función donde creo puedo crear tablas temporales privadas, el codigo es asi

```
function tmpTable($nombreTmp,$tipo,$query = "",$where = "") {
 global $ln;
 switch ($tipo) {
    case '1':
        // Creacion de la tabla temporal
        $qryCreation = $ln->query("CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE 
                                        ".'ORA$PTT_'."$nombreTmp 
                                    ON COMMIT PRESERVE DEFINITION
                                    AS ($query)");
        return $qryCreation = $ln->fetch($qryCreation);
    break;

    case '2':
        // Busqueda de datos
        $qrySearch = "  SELECT 
                            * 
                        FROM 
                            ".'ORA$PTT_'."$nombreTmp 
                        $where";
        return $qrySearch;
    break;

    case '3':
        //Eliminacion de datos
        $qryDelete = $ln->query("DROP TABLE ".'ORA$PTT_'."$nombreTmp");
        echo "Tabla $nombreTmp eliminada";
    break;
    
    default:
        echo "<br>No existe la opción<br>";
    break;
  }
}
```

Esto lo estoy llamando en dos partes diferentes en una estoy creando la tabla temporal y en otro estoy llamando esa tabla temporal para hacer un poco más rápido las consultas debido a que son muy pesadas, todo esto lo ejecuto en una misma sesión pero no entiendo porque aveces se pierde la tabla, me aparece el error de que la tabla o vista no existe, ¿alguien sabe porque sucede y si existe alguna forma de evitar que ese error aparezca?.

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Comment: Cuando dices _todo esto lo ejecuto en una misma sesión_, ¿te refieres a la sesión de PHP o a la misma petición HTTP y usando la misma conexión? Supongo que las sesiones de Oracle están basadas en la conexión. Viendo que tienes el control de creación y eliminación de la tabla, te sugiero cambiar de PRIVATE a GLOBAL.

Comment: A la misma petición HTTP usando la misma conexion, voy a intentarlo haber que sucede, cambiar de PRIVATE a GLOBAL haber que sucede

Comment: Perdon que responda hasta ahora, sigue con el mismo error, se pierde la tabla pareciera como una variable session solo funciona cuando se recarga la página, estoy buscando la solución pero aun no la encuentro, alguna otra recomendación?

Comment: Revisa todas las llamadas a la función `tmpTable()` y si el flujo del programa es adecuado.